# Can two modules work in local directory with different name and controller functions

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, local, admin-controller

I am creating local module for overriding core controller of magento  ProductController.php. I created two local folders Module1 and Module2 with accessibility of ProductController.php init. My question is if i use two different functions in new controller files of two different modules. Say in first i use "saveAction" and in another file i use "deleteAction". Then can both controllers code work or not?

Comment: You can use the event observer rather then overriding the controller, as it is not advice to override controller.

Comment: How can i do this.

Comment: You can find the events  list in in the following link, https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/  And follow this tutorial https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/12/making-use-of-observers-in-magento/ to implement observer

Comment: I want save function observer any example how i can use "catalog_product_prepare_save" .